# MU0 instruction set

Tags: computer-architecture

As i know the MU0 processor instruction format is as follows:

[image]

so the opcode is 4 bit, can anyone explain why it has only 8 instructions, if it could have 16 instructions,  2^4 = 16 ??

Comment: maybe it doesn't need more than 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mu0 microprocessor was designed for teaching purposes.  As such, it was deliberately designed to be extremely simple.  Having a simple instruction set is a benefit for teaching: it enables you to focus on core concepts, without being distracted by unnecessary complexity.  Thus, presumably the designers of the mu0 designed their instruction set to have as few as instructions as possible, given their teaching goals.  In this case, it doesn't need more than those 8 instructions; those are more than enough to illustrate the primary concepts.

Comment: The immediate question is, then, why not formatting the instruction as 3bits opcode + 13bits address bits. I'd believe the answer is that it is a good engineering practice to leave slack for provisional expansions. It's also good for homework and exams (;